# Building a semi-private Google Apps Script add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I would have a question related to the building of Google Apps Script add-ons for Google Docs, for instance.

Let's say I build an add-on for Google Docs and I want this add-on to be used only by a specific group of users (i.e. a group of students in a university course). Let's say this add-on requires the users to login with credentials provided by the university for that course in order to use the add-on.

Is that possible technically speaking and is that allowed by Google and is there a way of making this add-on not public to everyone in the world but only to those I want?

Any info will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restrict an Add-On to a Domain name.

[Apply to Publish](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish#apply_to_publish)

[image: Domain restricted]

Comment: Thanks for the very quick reply.

I'll take a look at this option. However, what does "domain-restricted" mean? How can I create a domain for Google Docs, for instance? Is it related to having a Google for Work account?

Where can I get more info about how to create this kind of domain which would allow me to create an add-on and then make it available ONLY for users in that domain?

Comment: Sorry, don't know at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Domain restricted means that you have one of the following services:
- Gsuite (formerly Google Apps) for Work
- Gsuite for Education

To get a Gsuite account you have to sign up. Unless you are an educational organisation, it does cost/seat.

There is currently an issue with Gsuite Edu accounts that you cannot create developer profiles unless your organisation declares itself to be a university... Whether that makes a difference legally speaking to your contract, I don't know. You will need to ask your lawyers to check that one!

If you are at Gsuite organisation which has set the admin switch in the backend to 'university', then you should be able to build and publish appscript applications as add-ons and publish them to other students. Depending on your organisation's settings you may need to persuade the university sysadmins to do the publishing for you. You never know, it is worth asking!

You can then publish the add-on to members of those domains privately.

These links should help:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/domain-wide

https://support.google.com/a/answer/4530135

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle